# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to get a text from a certain row of my database. For this, I made this function

```
public String getTranslation(long rowId) throws SQLException {    
    String str = null;
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(
        true, TABLE_LANGUAGE_FR, new String[] {
            KEY_ID_INTERFACE_TEXT, KEY_ITEM_NAME,KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID, KEY_FORM_RANK
        }, 
        KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null
    );

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        str = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_NAME));
    }
    return str;
}
```

and I call it like this :

```
db = new DbAdapter(this);
db.createDatabase(); 
db.openDataBase();
String str = db.getTranslation(1706);
```

My table looks like this :

[image]

I get this error :

```
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.Orange.Database.DbAdapter.getTranslation(DbAdapter.java:141)
09:32:08.965    307 com.Orange  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.Orange.Authentication.onCreate(Authentication.java:32)
```

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25):

It would seem like you have an emtpy cursor. Instead of checking whether it is null try checkcing

```
if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

try removing your where condition to make sure you actually get data when running the select statement.
If you still get nothing you might have a typo in your tablenames, or failed to connect/create the database/tables.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query("sys_interface_text", new String[] {
       "id_interface_text", "item_name","form_label_id", "form_rank"}, 
               "form_label_id = 1706", null, null, null,
       null);
```

Comment: I put this condition and I see that my cursor's count is 0, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Read Khan's answer, your db. query doesn't match the syntax described at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html
removing "true" from the parameters might do the trick

Comment: I changed my query as Khan said, but still the same problem.

Comment: have you double checked for typo's in the table and db names? and tried replacing "KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID + "=" + rowId" with "null"

Comment: I checked the table and db for many times and I didn't find any mistake. I get the cursor null and I don't see why.

Comment: just for kicks, try the edit in my answer. If it still doesn't work, can you post the code of your class handling this method?

Comment: With your code I don't get the Cursor null, but if I put "form_label_id"+"="+rowId it became null. There is another method to write this ?

Comment: try writing it static like in the answer for a start

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13209/discussion-between-user744610-and-gabrielle)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
   if(cursor.isFirst())
   {
      //Your code goes here in your case
      return mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_NAME));
   }
}
finaly
{
 if(mCursor!= null)
 {
   mCursor.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try by changing this line

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_LANGUAGE_FR, new String[] {
           KEY_ID_INTERFACE_TEXT, KEY_ITEM_NAME,KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID, KEY_FORM_RANK}, 
                   KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null,
           null, null);
```

by

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_LANGUAGE_FR, new String[] {
           KEY_ID_INTERFACE_TEXT, KEY_ITEM_NAME,KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID, KEY_FORM_RANK}, 
                   KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null,
           null);
```

and also add this in if condition

```
 return str;
```

Comment: one more plz check ur column name and tablename should be same as in database not having any spelling mistakes too this may cause problem

Comment: which type of column KEY_FORM_LABEL_ID  is