# Android SQLite database fatal exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I calll getNote() method , program throws exception

```
public Cursor getNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor cursor = Db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_BODY }, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor !=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Here is Exception. This is not the whole exception .

```
07-03 06:46:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 06:46:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2556): Process: com.vahe_muradyan.notes, PID: 2556
07-03 06:46:02.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2556): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vahe_muradyan.notes/com.vahe_muradyan.notes.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Here is notes.db file

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please make sure your table has been created and also mention your create table query here.

Comment: table is created, I can insert data in it . I am using Root Browser to view that database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your cursor is empty. So instead of checking null cursor try checking -

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  //Empty cursor
}
```

Then check where the control is going - going in `if condition` or in `else condition`.

**UPDATE**:

Since the cursor.getCount() returned 0, so there is no data in your cursor.

To get data you can do following -

```
Cursor cursor = Db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_BODY }, COLUMN_ID + "= 2", null,
                null, null, null, null);
```

**NOTE:**

`rowid = 2` is the row id from your table `TABLE_NAME`. You can check this table and see what `rowid` is there for this table and substitute it in place of `2`.

The problem is because your dynamic `rowid` is not matched with your any of the table `rowid`.

**ILLUSTRATION** -

---

```
| _ID      |   TITLE     |   NOTES    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1        |   jsush     |   -----    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2        |   jsushshai |   -----    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Looking at the table, it is clear that you have only two `rowid` values `1` and `2`.
So if your query does not match any of these values from its `rowid` then the cursor will be empty.

You passed the rowid value in a method `getNote(long rowId)` which doesn't match any of the table rowid.

The similar situation is here you can look for more help -

[cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size-of-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257369/cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size-of-0)

**UPDATE:**

Try this -

```
public Cursor getNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor cursor = Db.query("notes", new String[] { "_ID",
                "TITLE", "NOTES"}, "_ID=1", null,
                null, null, null, null);

      cursor.moveToFirst();

      if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
      {
        //do stuff
      }
      else
      {
        //Empty cursor
      }

        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: cursor.getCount() returned 0 . But how can I get data from database?

Comment: @user3693550 - you can put static rowid in your query. Look your table for rowid and put in your program to get the non empty cursor.

Comment: @user3693550 - This is the example to illustrate the cause. Check your table about the actual values that it has and replace in place of `121` or `122` in program.

Comment: I have added pictures of my notes.db file

Comment: and how can I get real ID ? not the dynamic ?

Comment: @user3693550 - By using the select query to this table you can get the id from this table and then pass any value from it to the `getNote` method.

Comment: Cursor cursor = DbAdapter.getNote(1);
     int count = cursor.getCount();
and again count = 0 .

Comment: what does cursor.moveToFirst function?

Comment: @user3693550 - It moves the cursor to the first row of table.

Comment: again the same . cursor != null but cursor.getCound() = 0

Comment: @user3693550 - Why you used  `cursor != null` ? Just use my code above. How you predicted `cursor.getCount()` to be `0` ? Which part is executed from my code - the if part or the else part ?

Comment: again cursor.getCount() == 0 . I think I should use rawQuery instead of query . Do you know how to use it?

Comment: I got the way . I wrote getAllNotes() method and then cursor.moveToFirst() and I got first row . Thank you .!!!))

Answer (score 2):

You should check `cursor.moveToFirst();` like so

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
//data found 
}
else{
//No data
}
```

### Update:

try this way for getting data from `DB` for that used `.rawQuery(.....)` method of `SQLite`

```
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_ID = ?";

  Cursor cursor=Db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { String.valueOf(COLUMN_ID_VALUE));

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           String first_column = cursor.getString(0); 
           String second_column=cursor.getString(1); 
   }
```

Comment: cursor.getCount() returned 0 . But how can I get data from database?

Comment: which is difference between query and rawQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {

   // YOUR CODE HERE                
}
```

That is the best approach so far to safely iterate over cursors in android and will make sure you won't get `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Try commenting this line  like so ... //cursor.moveToFirst(); and check if that solves any problems ...