# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to get a single row from my sqlite database.When I run this line of code :-

```
  RReckoner_info rReckoner_info = dbHandler.get_subcategory(1);
        Log.d("INFO : ", rReckoner_info.getCategory_name());
```

I get the following error:-

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

```
  public RReckoner_info get_subcategory(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SUBCATEGORY_LIST, new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_DESC, KEY_CATEGORY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1,KEY_CONTENTTYPE1,KEY_CONTENT2,KEY_CONTENTTYPE2,KEY_CONTENT3,KEY_CONTENTTYPE3,
                KEY_CONTENT4,KEY_CONTENTTYPE4,KEY_CONTENT5,KEY_CONTENTTYPE5,KEY_CONTENT6,KEY_CONTENTTYPE6,KEY_ORDERID,KEY_STATUS ,KEY_UPDATED},KEY_NAME +"=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null, null,null);
        if (cursor !=null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        RReckoner_info rReckoner_info = new RReckoner_info(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
                cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6)
                ,cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),
                cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),
                Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(15)),cursor.getString(16),cursor.getString(17));

        return rReckoner_info;

    }
```

Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem.Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: it says, there are no items returned and you're trying to access the first item of your cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11257527/2435238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code

**From :**

```
if (cursor !=null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
RReckoner_info rReckoner_info = new RReckoner_info(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
            cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6)
            ,cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),
            cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(15)),cursor.getString(16),cursor.getString(17));

return rReckoner_info;
```

**To :**

```
if (cursor !=null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        RReckoner_info rReckoner_info = new RReckoner_info(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
            cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6)
            ,cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),
            cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(15)),cursor.getString(16),cursor.getString(17));

    return rReckoner_info;
    }
return null;
```

In case of no rows found I am returning `null`, you can change this last part though based on your requirement, but you have to check the `count` of cursor to avoid `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
    if (cursor !=null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

       RReckoner_info rReckoner_info = new RReckoner_info(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
            cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6)
            ,cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),
            cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(15)),cursor.getString(16),cursor.getString(17));

        return rReckoner_info;
   }
   return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no records extracted by your query, as the [CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) indicated:

> An exception indicating that a cursor is out of bounds.

Check if there is at least a record:

```
 if (cursor !=null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
     cursor.moveToFirst();


   // Code to extract data
}
```

Or you can do the following because [moveToFirst](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) return false if no record is present

> This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // Code to extract data
}
```